# Is there an option to make nice grayscale pgfplots figures?

Tags: pgfplots

I am writing an academic journal paper,
and we are at the final stage of proofing,
where we need to submit grayscale figures.
Is there an option that I can supply to pgfplots
so that the plots automatically become grayscale?
I am aware of `\selectcolormodel{gray}`,
but using this with the default pgfplots color and mark choices,
the output doesn't look nice and distinct in grayscale.
For example, the overlapping marks in the image below are not clear.

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\selectcolormodel{gray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,3) (4,4)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am aware that it is possible
to use imagemagick to convert the PDF output into grayscale,
but it would be more convenient if the PDF output were already grayscale.

Comment: I usually revise figures to alter colour as required: here there's no issue with black-and-white, but if you've got a series of say coloured lines you'll need to use an alternative (_e.g._ patterns) if you are only allowed greyscale. Not sure this is something one should leave to automation.

Comment: perhaps useful to create your own `cycle list`?...

Comment: ... or just use the `cycle list` `black white` by adding `cycle list name=black white,` to the `axis` environment for each plot or to `\pgfplotsset` to apply it as default to all plots.

Comment: BTW, in your example I'd expect a 'real' case to use different symbols for the two lines (I go for filled, empty and half-filled circles, as using some rotation you can get quite a lot of variation)

Comment: You might also want to use things like \addplot+[dashed] and \addplot+[dotted]

Answer (score 3):

I found that defining my only `cycle list`
using dashed, dotted, and carefully chosen marks
helps to make the two data lines distinct from each other.

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{grayscale}{
    thick,white!20!black,mark=o,mark options=solid,densely dotted\\%
    thick,white!50!black,mark=x,mark options=solid,dashed\\%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[cycle list name=grayscale]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,3) (4,4)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]